# How to Automate Building modules each time when there is a Change in Source Code in a Modular Style Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am currently working on a modular Maven Project. I am using Tomcat6 & Eclipse Neon. I need some guidance related to **working in (Local) Development Environment**.

**Current Setup:**

We have 4 Modules (Java Projects) M1, M2, M3, M4.

My **parent pom.xml** builds 4 jar files corresponding to 4 modules first and finally builds two war files A.war, B.war.

A uses M1.jar, M2.jar, M3.jar

B uses M2.jar, M3.jar, M4.jar

The required modules are packaged into jar files and placed in the lib folders of A.war and B.war

So, locally while developing, if I change anything (Java code) in any of the module,

(i)  I am stopping the tomcat server (added in eclipse)
(ii) I am building that sub project (module)'s POM.xml to generate jar file.
(iii) Generated jar file is copied into the lib folder of exploded war files manually.
(iv) Start the tomcat server.

Is there any way better than this. I dont want to build (an entire) jar file each time when there is a change in java file and copy it to lib folder of exploded war file manually.

Please let me know if anything related to the post is not clear.

Thank you,

Vivek.

Comment: Use Eclipse workspace dependency resolution?

Comment: This isn't clear. Why do you want to avoid building the downstream Jars when the corresponding code has changed?

Comment: How are you building A.war and B.war, do they don't have dependency on respective modules

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I dont want to build whole jar file, if I just change single .java file. To build jar file it is taking 1-2 minutes; I am looking for a better approach than this. There must be a way.